# Email sending from iOS

Tags: objective-c, ipad, email

Can I send email messages from my iPad application without using MFMailComposeViewController? Its possible to use SBSendMail in iOS?

Comment: What's wrong with the mail composer? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to send email without the user's knowledge/interaction? The fact that you can't send email without the user's knowledge is a feature, not an obstacle. I wouldn't want your app sending emails around using my email address without my permission.

Comment: Because MFMailComposeViewController leaks. I seen many complaints of mail compose leakage, and I didn't recieve answer about mail compose leakage there.

Comment: @user578205: Does Instruments say the leak is with objects that aren't created by you ?

Comment: @user578205 I answered your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789443/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-uses-toooo-many-of-memory/5802114#5802114

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, there is no other native way to send e-mails except with MFMailComposerViewController.
2. No, you cannot use SBSendMail as that is only available on Mac (and is just a demo, BTW).

You could implement your own SMTP client to interface with a mail server (which would be a *lot* of work) or maybe there's an implementation out there that you could port, but it still wouldn't be of any use to you as you can't query which e-mail server(s) are configured in the iPhone/iPad.

Comment: Please at least link to the sources where you've taken this information for your answer.In this case,http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html   which is really useful for the poster.

Answer (score 2):

To send mail in iOS, you need to use MFMailComposeViewController. SBSendMail is for sending mail in Mac OS.

[Check this link.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SBSendEmail/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: In "leaks" tool my objects and MFMailComposeViewController's object succesfully killed. But part of MFMailComposeViewController referenced classes is still live and will continue to accumulation of used memory after each MFMailComposeViewController's opening.
If attachement contains 1mb of data, then 20mb of memory uses, if attachement is 5mb - 100mb of memory. After closing mail view controller, not all of memory freed

Comment: MFMailComposeViewController is the controller for sending mails. I have not heard of any leaks in MFMailComposeViewController. Please go throught the docs provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can now to this using [URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) in iOS. You would specific the url scheme of the app you wanted to use, and call `UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)` on it.

I have written a blog post on this matter [here](https://medium.com/@harrybloom18/ios-email-picker-99045d940a3d) if you wanted a closer look